# Prevent fullpage.js scroll while timelineMax animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, gsap

I am using timelineMax into my project along with fullpage.js, I don't want my current slide to slide up until my timelineMax animation is finished.

So, for that I have used onComplete event in my timelineMax and assigned a function `nextAnimation` to it.

**timelineMax**

```
t1 = new TimelineMax({delay:1, onComplete:nextAnimation});
```

and within `nextAnimation` function I have following code.

```
function nextAnimation() {  
    alert("animation is onComplete");
    $('#main-pages').fullpage({
        autoScrolling:false
    });
}
```

But fullpage js scroll is not disabled though I can still slide down to next slide.

Comment: Possible for you to create a jsFiddle or a Codepen demo please?

Comment: @TahirAhmed: unfortunately it is not possible to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable/enable the scrolling you should be using [`$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrollingboolean-directions) function instead.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful plugin.. I will surely try your solution and will get back to you..

Comment: did this approach by @Alvaro work for you? If it did, please accept this answer.